# Using security questions and its safety

Tags: php, security

I know Security Questions are not safe and easily guessed but what if after answering the security question we just send the securely prepared link to recover/reset the password to their email? Will that be again a problem?

And I also use PDO in my codes so no worries on SQL injection.

Comment: Sending a reset link to the user's verified email should suffice.

Comment: and use a one-time token, and deleted after confirmed.

Comment: what's wrong w SMS MFA or TOTP MFA?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan, I am not that much experienced, what do you mean?

Comment: @Serjio use multi-factor authentication

Comment: Where to start? any links for more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a strong opponent of security questions: they give a [false sense of security](http://www.newsfactor.com/story.xhtml?story_id=111003TUXP8C).

While the authoritative source for application security is [OWASP](http://owasp.org) and how to deal with forgotten passwords is covered in their [Forgot Password Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Forgot_Password_Cheat_Sheet), there is no added value which would compensate this false sense of security.

If you really need to use them, follow the guidelines in the cheat sheet.

If you have a concern about your users being spammed by requests, you can add a rate limit or a captcha.

Comment: By the way, your newsfactor link tries to shame users with ad-blockers. :(

Comment: @ScottArciszewski: you are right (I missed that on my mobile which happily displayed the ads - which my brain automatically discarded). Fortunately we are all grown-ups and will not be ashamed to do what we think is the best action (press 'OK' or whitelist or never come back)

Comment: It's cool, I just wanted to let you know in case you had alternatives on-hand. :)

Comment: @ScottArciszewski: I will look for the original source of the research (Google's) and replace the link for the article. Also because I liked your article about password storage very much :)